# readline function not working as expected

Tags: python, file, io

The below code is run as part of thread. When the file is opened and we keep appending the file, the file size is getting incremented properly but the line is empty. Both the line and file size are printed in line 5. Not able to understand what is the issue in io module.

```
with io.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
  file.seek(0, 2)  # Seek to the end of the file
  while not self._stop_event.is_set():
    line = file.readline()
    print(f"LINE  = {line}  FILE SIZE = {os.path.getsize(file_path)}") #LINE 5
    if not line:
      time.sleep(1)
    else:
      print(f"LINE : {line.strip()}")
```

I have tried to open the file and keep appending to it. It will keep incrementing the filesize as and when we keep including new lines to file. Not able to know where is the exact issue.

Comment: What do you expect to read *after* you `Seek to the end of the file`?

Comment: when the thread for the file is running, the file will be opened and it will be pointing at the end. Now, i will include some lines in the file, then the readline should read the new line and print it, which is not happening, but filesize is getting incremented.

Comment: What is appending to the file? Note that you are getting the size by opening whatever file is referenced by the same name, which may *not* be the same file that was referenced by that name when you called `io.open`. (Maybe the old file was replaced by a new  copy with the same name, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show how you're appending to the file.

Note that opening a file for writing (in text mode) will be buffered. Therefore, after each line is written, it's important to flush the buffer. Either that or open in line-buffered mode if the data being written contains either carriage return or newline.

Here's an emulation of what you appear to be trying to do that works as expected:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout

RUN = True
FILENAME = "foo.txt"
EVENT = Event()

def tail():
    with open(FILENAME) as fd:
        fd.seek(0, 2)
        EVENT.wait()
        while RUN:
            if line := fd.readline():
                # stdout is line-buffered
                # therefore, as our data has a newline character at its end, there's no need to flush
                stdout.write(line)
            else:
                sleep(0.25)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (thread := Thread(target=tail)).start()
    # By opening the file in line-buffered mode, there's no need to flush
    # providing the output contains either a carriage return or newline.
    # If the file is opened in text mode without buffering=1 then it will
    # be necessary to flush after each write
    with open(FILENAME, "a", 1) as fd:
        for i in range(10):
            fd.write(f"Line {i}\n")
            if i == 0:
                EVENT.set()
            sleep(1)

    RUN = False
    thread.join()
```

**Output:**

```
Line 0
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

**Note:**

There will be intervals of ~1s between each of the output lines.
The Event is required to guarantee proper synchronisation between the main program and the thread.